# How to deal with variables with digits in name with mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, variables, scatter-plot

Hey guys I'm going through this data set with python and I don't know how to create the plot for this variable that has a digit in it (`"firstflrSF"` vs `"1stflrSF"`). I get the invalid syntax error, since variable names in python can't have digits in it, so how can I get past this? The code is below

```py
# Visualization of corr btwn vars 1stFlrSF & SalePrice
plt.scatter(df_train.1stFlrSF, df_train.SalePrice)
plt.show()
```

This is the error I get when I run it:

```
 File "<ipython-input-33-fb572b360162>", line 3
    plt.scatter(df_train.1stFirSF, df_train.SalePrice)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming df_train is a pandas DataFrame and you are trying to access a column, you can just do `df_train['1stFlrSF']`.